# Steffensen's method in Numerical Analysis

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

In some sources, Steffensen's method is the development of Newton's method to avoid computing the derivative,

- http://bit.do/Um6M
- http://cims.nyu.edu/~donev/Teaching/NMI-Fall2010/Homework4.pdf
- http://www.hrpub.org/download/201309/ujam.2013.010215.pdf
- http://folk.uib.no/ssu029/Pdf_file/Varona02.pdf

But in the other sources it's the modification of Aitken's Method,

- http://bit.do/Um6P
- http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat460/fall09/lecture13.pdf
- http://bruce-shapiro.com/math481A/notes/13-Steffensen.pdf
- http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~jmahaffy/courses/s10/math541/lectures/pdf/week04/lecture.pdf

Is there two version of Steffensen's method?

Comment: URLs will automatically generate links. Incredibly, you have managed to bypass this feature.

Comment: There's notification that not allowed me to post more than 2 links when I want to post it.

Comment: That's because questions that are just a bunch of links are discouraged strongly.

Answer (score 1):

There are not two different versions. The links you provide describe the relationship between the methods well. The methods as described are identical. The key is to envision the sequence of finite differences as a sequence as described in the derivation of Aitken's method, in other words $$p_i \stackrel{\textrm{def}}{=} \frac{f(x_{i})}{h}.$$

Then,

$$\Delta p = p_{i+1}-p_i = \frac{f(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)}{h}.$$